# How to add up all instances of a class. This total value will be available through the class as well as any of the instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Any instance of the class `Square` starts as an integer equal to 2. When the `square_me` method is called on the instance, the instance is multiplied by itself. This can be done any number of times (e.g. calling `square_me` once on an instance results in the value 4, and calling `square_me` again on the same instance results in the value 16, etc.).

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self):
        self.integer = 2

    def square_me(self):
        self.integer = self.integer * self.integer

    def get_me(self):
        return self.integer

n1 = Square()
n2 = Square()
n3 = Square()

n1.square_me()
val1 = n1.get_me()
print(val1)               # 4

n2.square_me()
n2.square_me()
val2 = n2.get_me()
print(val2)               # 16
```

This was straightforward enough, however, I also want the class `Square` to keep track of the total value of all instances. This total value should be available through the class as well as any of the instances.

For example:

```
print(val1)               # 4
print(val2)               # 16
print(Square.total)       # 20
```

I tried adding each instance to a dictionary and summing the values within it. While I can sum the dictionary values outside of the class and get the correct answer with `print(sum(Square.instances.values()))`, I want to design it so that the class `Square` tracks the total value of all instances. Instead, it just prints:

`<function Square.get_total at 0x000001CADA21B0D0>`

I feel like I'm close to a solution but need some guidance. This is my code:

```
class Square:

    instances = {}
    total = sum(instances.values())

    def __init__(self):
        self.integer = 2

    def square_me(self):
        self.integer = self.integer * self.integer
        self.instances[self] = (self.integer)

    def get_total(self):
        return self.total

    def get_me(self):
        return self.integer

n1 = Square()
n2 = Square()

n1.square_me()
val1 = n1.get_me()
print(val1)               # 4

n2.square_me()
n2.square_me()
val2 = n2.get_me()
print(val2)               # 16

print(Square.instances) # Print the dictionary.
print(sum(Square.instances.values())) # This works.
print(Square.get_total) # This does not work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Square.get_total` is a function. You need `Square.get_total()`.  In that case, `get_total` is not going to get a `self` argument.  Also, you never update `total`, so it's going to return anything.  You would need `get_total` to do `return sum(Square.instances.values())`.  Also, you'll want to store the instance in the list during initialization, not just after a `square_me` call.  Like this:

```
class Square:

    instances = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.integer = 2
        Square.instances[self] = self.integer

    def square_me(self):
        self.integer = self.integer * self.integer
        Square.instances[self] = self.integer

    @classmethod
    def get_total(cls):
        return sum(cls.instances.values())

    def get_me(self):
        return self.integer

n1 = Square()
n2 = Square()

n1.square_me()
val1 = n1.get_me()
print(val1)               # 4

n2.square_me()
n2.square_me()
val2 = n2.get_me()
print(val2)               # 16
print(sum(Square.instances.values())) # This works.
print(Square.get_total()) # This does not work.
```

Output:

```
4
16
20
20
```